# Using linq's orderby and thenby keywords, can I sort a matrix by rows?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, matrix

I have a 2 dimensional matrix that I would like to sort by rows.   Can this be done in LINQ using the orderby keyword?

I understand that 'datatables' such as from sql databases can be sorted by various fields using LINQ in dot-net.   But can this be done with matrixes, where you want to sort by the first column, and then within that by the second column, and then with that result by the third column?

LINQ can sort tables with syntax as follows:

```
var studentsOrderByRank = from student in students
                            orderby student.Rank, student.Age
                            select student;
```

My question is with matrices such as ( for example):

```
0,1,1
1,0,1
0,1,0
```

which I would want to become

```
0,1,0
0,1,1
1,0,1
```

To sum up, I need a way to give any matrix of doubles or floats to a routine, and then get back the matrix sorted by row, or more specifically, the first column is the primary sort key, the second column is the second, the third column is the third, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you actually mean when you say "matrix"?  Are you talking about a multi-dimensional array?  If so, the answer is no.  If you are talking about a specific `Matrix` type, it depends on the definition of that type.  LINQ operates on instance of the `IEnumerable(Of T)` type, where `T` is the type of the items in the list.  Does your "matrix" implement that interface?  If not then LINQ is not an option for anything.

Comment: System.Array implements the [IStructuralComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.istructuralcomparable) Interface, used to provide a Comparer that can determine if a collection object precedes or follows another when sorted. See the examples there.